# What is the best way to ensure that all inputs are all unique Numbers

Tags: java

Here is an example inputs:

String test = "1 2 3 4 5 42";
String test2 = test.replaceAll(" ","");

```
public static boolean uniqueNumbers(String test2) {
    char[] testEntries= test2.toCharArray();
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < testEntries.length ; i++ ) {
        if(!set.add(testEntries[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Despite all are unique number, it will return as false. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It’s because you’re checking for duplicate characters, not numbers. Although 4 and 42 are distinct, both contain a 4, so it returns false.

Comment: You are removing all the spaces using `test.replaceAll(" ","")`, so the number you are checking is `1234542`. How do you plan to distinguish the `2` and `4` from `42` in that number?

Comment: Ye, that is the part where I am stuck. I understand that it return false between its checking 1234542.

Comment: You will need to pass the original string to `uniqueNumbers`, because if you pass the string where you already replaced the spaces, it is already too late to distinguish `2` and `4` from `42`. Then just split the string on the space so you get an array of all the separate numbers instead of an array of every single character.

Answer (score 3):

You should split your input argument with split() at first.

```
String test = "1 2 3 4 5 42";
String[] origin = test.split(" ");
Set<String> check = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(origin));
for (String el : check) {
    System.out.println(el);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Catch `IllegalArgumentException` from `Set.of`

The [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E...)) convenience method in Java 9+ creates a `Set` of an unspecified implementation when passed an array. If any duplicates are encountered while building this `Set`, an exception is thrown. You can trap for that `IllegalArgumentException` to know if the parts of your string are distinct or not.

We can get an array of the parts of your string by calling [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

```java
Boolean isDistinct;
try
{
    Set.of( "1 3 3 4 5 42".split( " " ) );
    isDistinct = Boolean.TRUE;
}
catch ( IllegalArgumentException e )
{
    isDistinct = Boolean.FALSE;
}

System.out.println( "Input is distinct: " + Objects.requireNonNull( isDistinct ) );
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://Boolean%20isDistinct;%20try%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20Set.of(%20%221%203%203%204%205%2042%22.split(%20%22%20%22%20)%20);%20%20%20%20%20isDistinct%20=%20Boolean.TRUE;%20%7D%20catch%20(%20IllegalArgumentException%20e%20)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20isDistinct%20=%20Boolean.FALSE;%20%7D%20%20System.out.println(%20%22Input%20is%20distinct:%20%22%20+%20Objects.requireNonNull(%20isDistinct%20)%20);).

> Input is distinct: false

Answer (score 0):

By the time you are passing your String parameter to uniqueNumbers() it looks like

```
1234542
```

Splitting it into char array takes each single character as a separate element, printing out the output immediately for instance gives:

```
char[] testEntries = test2.toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testEntries));
//output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2]
```

So when passing each element to the set, it finds 2 repeated at index 1 and 6.

One solution in this case would be to pass the original to split test using String's instance split().

```
    String test = "1 2 3 4 5 42";
    String[] test2=test.split(" ");


    public static boolean uniqueNumbers(String testEntries[]) {

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < testEntries.length; i++) {
        if (!set.add(testEntries[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//output: true
```